# .htaccess rewrite rule takes place when it is a directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

With htaccess I look which page should be loaded and then I get the HTML document for that page.

The problem I have now, there is a directory called **api** and when this is called the rewrite should not take place, but it does.

**My .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9])\w+ index.php?page=$0 [QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you want me to change here for a better question? I have told you what it is doing and what it should do. Also I have as little code as needed @MarcinOrlowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with the following condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
```